# React - Uncaught ReferenceError: combinations is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

Im building a small gadget for a website that uses react. But its giving me a reference error when it says that my variable "combinations" is not defined as well that there is a TypeError: wrapper is null. It works but at the same time its giving a constant error.

```
import React from 'react';
import './portfolio.css';

const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
console.log(wrapper)
const rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

const uniqueRand = (min, max, prev) => {
  let next = prev;
  while(prev === next) next = rand(min, max);
  
  return next;
}

const combinations = [
  { configuration: 1, roundness: 1 },
  { configuration: 1, roundness: 2 },
  { configuration: 1, roundness: 3 },
  { configuration: 2, roundness: 2 },
  { configuration: 2, roundness: 3 }
];

let prev = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  const index = uniqueRand(0, combinations.length - 1, prev),
        combination = combinations[index];
  
  wrapper.dataset.configuration = combination.configuration;
  wrapper.dataset.roundness = combination.roundness;
  
  prev = index;
}, 3000);

const Portfolio = () => {
  return (
    <div className='RO__portfolio'>
      <div className='RO__portfolio-content' data-roundness="1" data-configuration ="1" id='wrapper'>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Portfolio
```

It should not be giving this to errors:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: combinations is not defined
- Uncaught TypeError: wrapper is null

Comment: For accessing dom elements in React you should use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: I have never used a ref in react, where can i put it in the portfolio function?